# mysql statement to get the rank of a given row id in an ordered result set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with multiple columns. The primary key of the table is the 'id' column. A row has multiple columns but the most relevant one for this question is 'Date' which is basically a timestamp. What is an efficient way to get the order (rank) of a given row id if I want to order the rows by their timestamp. The most recent timestamp is of rank 1, the second is of rank 2 and so on. I want to return the rank of a given row

Edit: I use ORDER BY to get an ordered set but I want the mysql statement to return the order of the specific item, not an ordered rows. I also don't want to parse the result set since this is very time cosnuming

Edit2: for example assume the following table

```
id    timestamp      name
 1    Dec 4, 2016    Bob
 2    Jan 1, 2015    Eve
 3    Feb 6, 2017    Alice
```

Given an id, I should return the order of the item

```
id=1, expected output: 2 
id=2, expected output: 3 (least recent)
id=3, expected output: 1 (most recent)
```

Comment: I doubt in over clause you are missing order by clause ..

Comment: can you show your table data structure with output you required

Comment: @jaidutt I made an edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer with out edit :Use row_number () over (order by )  clause and put some *dummy

```
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select1) ) as renk ,* from table
```

answer after edit in question..

```
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by timestamp  desc ) as renk ,* from table
```

Comment: thanks! is therea mysql equivalent without using join?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this in mysql

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT t.rank FROM
(SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, id
FROM `table_name` 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC) t WHERE t.id=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selct * from table where id>1 order by id asc limit 1
if( not date ){
   selct * from table where id>0 order by id asc limit 1
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What did you do and why does it work?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)